# dependendt dropdownlist in yii2

Tags: yii2, dropdown

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fk_int_category_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(TblCategory::find()->all(), 'pk_category_id','vchr_category_name'),
            ['prompt'=> 'Select a category',
             'onchange'=>'
                    $.post("index.php?r=product-size-variants/get-sub-category&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                        //alert(data);
                            $("select#tblproduct-fk_int_sub_category_id").html(data);
                    });',       
            ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'fk_int_sub_category_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(TblSubCategory::find()->all(), 'pk_sub_category_id','vchr_sub_category_name'),
            ['prompt'=> 'Select Sub category'
              'onchange'=>'
                    $.post("index.php?r=product-size-variants/get-sub-category&subId='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                        //alert(data);
                            $("select#tblproduct-fk_int_sub_category_id").html(data);
                    });'  
            ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'fk_int_product_variants')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(TblProductSizeVariants::find()->all(), 'pk_int_product_size_variants_id','vchr_size_names'),
            ['prompt'=> 'Select Product Size']) ?>
```

i have three dropdownlist In second dropdownlist work using first one,
and third dropdownlist dependent to 1st and 2nd dropDown.
how to i pass 2 values in this index.php?r=product-size-variants/get-sub-category&subId= url??? of second dropdown

Comment: index.php?r=product-size-variants/get-sub-category?firstKey=firstValue&secondkey=secoundValue&thirdKey=thirdValue.... and so on.

Comment: ok..but here how to i get the first dropdown id value in second dropdown value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is kind of mess, you might get caught error in writing js in php, where excape sequence has to be exectly to be same. i have done re-work. let me know if it working

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fk_int_category_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(TblCategory::find()->all(), 'pk_category_id','vchr_category_name'),
        ['prompt'=> 'Select a category',
         'onchange'=>'generateSubCat(this)',       
        ]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'fk_int_sub_category_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(TblSubCategory::find()->all(), 'pk_sub_category_id','vchr_sub_category_name'),
        ['prompt'=> 'Select Sub category'
          'onchange'=>'generateProductVariant(this)'  
        ]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'fk_int_product_variants')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(TblProductSizeVariants::find()->all(), 'pk_int_product_size_variants_id','vchr_size_names'),
        ['prompt'=> 'Select Product Size']) ?>

<script>
function generateSubCat(obj){
     $.post("index.php?r=product-size-variants/get-sub-category/?id="+obj.value, function(data){
        $("select#tblproduct-fk_int_sub_category_id").html(data);
    });
  }
 function generateProductVariant(obj){
    var catID=$('#tblproduct-fk_int_category_id').val();
    if(catID==""){
       alert("Please select category");
    }else{
        $.post("index.php?r=product-size-variants/get-sub-category/?id="+catID+"&subId="+obj.value, function(data){
            $("select#tblproduct-fk_int_sub_category_id").html(data);
        });
     }

  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following url for dependent dropdown that can help you.

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop#basic-usage